# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am writing a discord bot with node.js. I want the bot to send a message automatically when a member joins or leaves the channel. But I keep getting an error about the send function. Can you help me?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4URud.png

```
module.exports = (client) => {
    client.on('guildMemberRemove', (member) => {
        console.log(member);
        
    member.guild.channels.cache.get("1234567890912345678").send("byeee");
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`member.guild.channels.cache.get("1234567890912345678")` is undefined, so there is no `send()` function. You need to identify why that channel is undefined or doesn't exist or find that channel using another method.

Answer (score 0):

Just easily use this;

```js
const user = await client.users.fetch("user-id");
const message = await user.send({ 
embeds: [embed-here],
components: [component-here],
});
```